# How can I go to the Accessibility permissions section in System Settings (macOS Ventura) using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, accessibility

I basically know nothing about AppleScript, but I tried looking this problem up and found nothing that can help me.

How can I do what is described in the title?

Comment: I would help considerably to detail what exactly you are trying to accomplish to help you find a solution.

Comment: Alright, sorry for not being clear. I want to open system settings in the accecibility permission settings

Comment: To do what? What is it that you want to do?

Comment: I want to be able to run a command which will open this window https://imgur.com/a/lBatjFY

Comment: @ItaySharir, you're not making us want to help you.  Whan agarza asks what you want to accomplish, let's assume that the height of achievement doesn't stop at opening a window.  What is your end goal ?

Comment: I'm writing a script and a part of that script is installing an app called yabai. yabai needs to have accecibility permissions before the first time you start it otherwise it glitches. i want to make it easy for the user to give yabai accecibility permissions (Important detail: yabai is a command line app installed with homebrew, it's not a .app) so i want to open up a finder window with the yabai executable and the mentioned settings window and then the user will just have to drag the yabai executable to the settings window.